# differenciate under integral sign with using Leibniz Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There were many questions on MathematicsSE about Leibniz rule but I could not find any helpful solution for my question. 
I try to differenciate the following by Leibniz Rule with respect to $v(z)$

$$y=\int_{0}^{t}\left(\rho+h\left(s\left(z\right)\right)\right)\left(1-v\left(z\right)\right)dz$$

$h(s)$ is a function which is in terms of a variable $s$, which varies over time $t$.

What I do in order to resolve this one

$$\frac{dy}{dv}=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\rho+h\left(s\left(z\right)\right)\right)\left(1-v\left(z\right)\right)dz=-\int_{0}^{t}\left(\rho+h\left(s\left(z\right)\right)\right)dz$$

I am not sure at all if my calculation is correct. The thing which makes me suspicious is that $v$ is not a constant, which varies over time.

Also, as I use a general form for function $h(s)$, I think it is not possible to go beyond.

Any hints or suggestions ?

Comment: What has $h$ got to do with anything if you are differentiating $v$?

Comment: @Mattos I am not sure if I have understood well your question. $h(s(z))$ is a function which does not depend on $v$. I try to differenciate the expression with respect to $z$ but I am not sure if my calculation is correct.

Comment: You keep describing $h(s)$ in your equation, but it has nothing to do with what you are differentiating. So it is confusing for you to keep referring to it. Just use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Variable_limits_form).

Comment: @Mattos thanks,  so when I try use $\frac{d\varphi}{d\alpha}=\int_{a}^{b}f_{z}(x,\alpha)dx+f\left(b,\alpha\right) \frac{db}{d\alpha} -f\left(a,\alpha\right)\frac{da}{d\alpha}$, as the intervals $0$ and $t$ does not depend on $v$, last two expressions will be zero for the case above. In this case, I think my calculation is correct.

Comment: You seem to want a functional derivative as in variational calculus. The variation of the integral for the function $v$ is the function $-(ρ+h(s(z)))$, i.e., without the integral.